# Mixing RAM modules from different manufacturers

Tags: memory

I have the following PC configuration:

- Processor: i3-6100
- MB: Asus Maximus Ranger VIII
- RAM: HyperX Kingston Technology Fury Black 8 GB 2133 MHz CL14 DIMM DDR4 Internal Memory (HX421C14FB2/8)

I wish to add another RAM module.
E.g: Corsair Vengeance LPX 8GB DDR4 DRAM 2133MHz C13 Memory Red Kit for Systems
Or: Corsair 8GB Kit (1x 8GB) 2133 MHz CL15 288-Pin DIMM DDR4 RAM Memory (CMV8GX4M1A2133C15)

I wish to know if they would work well together?
Can I mix manufacturers?
Has anyone done it and it's ok?
AFAIK params are identical so it should work....

Answer (score 1):

Best would be to also use same CL - otherwise both will work with the lowest CL between them AFAIK. Apart from that - no, no issues, apart from it looking slightly worse ;)